# Socket.io-redis configuration not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-redis

I'm trying to set up socket.io-redis for a kubernetes deployment, but something is wrong with the configuration. It is partially working, in that I can see socket.io messages in redis using `redis-cli PSUBSCRIBE`, but I don't have access to any of socket.io-redis' functions.

`io.of('/').adapter.sockets()`, `io.of('/').adapter.allRooms()`and every other function that should be available upon the successful configuration of socket.io-redis is undefined. My configuration is below.

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {transports: ['websocket']});
const redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redisAdapter({port: 6379, host: '127.0.0.1'}));
```

I can't find any other cases of difficulty in what should be a simple configuration. I am using `socket.io 2.3.0` and `socket.io-redis 5.4.0` which should be compatible according to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying Socket.IO application on a Kubernetes cluster, that means multiple SocketIO servers (Pods), there are two things to take care of:

- **Enabling the sticky session feature:**
  when a request comes from a SocketIO client (browser) to your app, it gets associated with a particular session-id, these requests must be kept connecting with the same process (Pod in Kubernetes) that originated their ids.
- **Using the Redis adapter**

you can learn more about this from this Medium story  (source code available) [Medium](https://saphidev.medium.com/socketio-redis-at-a-scalable-gke-cluster-with-github-workflows-844318f80ce)